# Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts after upgrade

Tags: networking, 18.04

I get this error when I try to start Ubuntu 18.04 and GUI doesn't show up:

> Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts 
>   Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

I tried to ping some sites and I got:

> Network is unreachable or Name or service not known.

I tried:

```
sudo rm- f /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

and

```
sudo /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd
```

I tried installing lightdm, but this didn't solve my problem.
When I run `sudo apt get update`, I get a bunch of errors.

I also get get hardware errors:

```
CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 
Bank 6: ee000000040110a. TSC 0 ADDR fef82380 MISC f8a0000086. 
PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1578183450 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 1c
```

How to solve this problem? I didn't have problems on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Do any network connections work properly?

Comment: No, i tried cable and Wifi, both doesnt work

Comment: The GUI-not-showing-up *might* be related to your general-networking-failure...but it also might not. Did the GUI and networking ever work on your 18.04? Is this a new install or new upgrade?

Comment: It was working for a 20 hours after upgrade.At one point network stopped working and the icons disappeared from the screen.  Then I tried to restart but it showed me tty

Comment: There does not seem to be any causal connection that you have identified: A crash of the desktop will usually not kill networking. The loss of networking will usually not crash the desktop. Check your /var/log/syslog for clues. Also try a LiveUSB to rule in/out hardware fault.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I forgot to mention that I get hardware errors: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee000000040110a.       TSC 0 ADDR fef82380 MISC f8a0000086. PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1578183450 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 1c

Answer (score 2):

From [https://ubuntu-mate.community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-update-upgrade-anymore-um-18-04-v2-lts/19745/2):

> I edited "/etc/update-manager/meta-release"
>
> ...from https to http:
>
> ```
> [METARELEASE]
> URI_LTS = http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts*
> ```

For me it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me `ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem` did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

If below command results in error,

```
resolvectl query changelogs.ubuntu.com
changelogs.ubuntu.com: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
```

first, check if network connection is ok:

```
ping -c 4 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=6.17 ms  
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=6.33 ms  
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=6.22 ms  
   
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---  
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, **0% packet loss**, time 3004ms
```

then, if so, appropriate nameservers should be specified in /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Check and modify to have this suggested line:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Save file and check name resolution again:

```
resolvectl query changelogs.ubuntu.com
changelogs.ubuntu.com: 91.189.91.48            -- link: eth0  
                            91.189.91.49            -- link: eth0  
                            185.125.190.18          -- link: eth0  
                            185.125.190.17          -- link: eth0  
                            2620:2d:4000:1::2b      -- link: eth0  
                            2620:2d:4000:1::2a      -- link: eth0  
      
     -- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 48.9ms.  
     -- Data is authenticated: no; Data was acquired via local or encrypted transport: no  
     -- Data from: network
```

`sudo apt update` should be fine, if network connection is fine.

Disclaimer: the above are in effect today, with Ubuntu 22.04, and settings in `/etc/netplan/` have no effect, in regard with DNS settings.